# Is there a setting in R to automatically convert same column names in a data frame when the data is loaded?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sqldf

I have been having a issue in R program while running my code in dplyr and sqldf.

For a data frame containing identical column names for example:

```
a    b        c        a

1    True     String   3.14
2    True     Boolean  2.18
3    False    Integer  0
```

dplyr and sqldf libraries throw the following error:

'Error: duplicate column name: a'

However in my organization, no one else faces this error.
Instead for them what happens is that the later duplicate column name automatically gets converted to column_name..column_number.

So for the above data frame, the fourth column would be automatically renamed as "a..4".

This was not a major issue for me yet since I could always rename the columns in my code using

`colnames(dataframe)[4] <- a..4`

But now since the data size will increase and the code I write will be shared among my team members, I want to avoid any confusion.

So I wanted to know whether there is a setting I should change in Rstudio that automatically converts the duplicate column name?

Comment: How are you importing your data exactly? `read.csv()`/`read.table()` etc. have the `check.names` argument set to `TRUE`, so it should not import it with duplicated column names.

Comment: `names(df) <- make.names(names(df), unique = TRUE)`

Comment: @tmfmnk We use read.csv()

Comment: @sindri_baldur will definitely try this, but as I mentioned my colleagues don't face this issue, it is only me, that is they don't have to run any additional lines of code, the column names are changed with read.csv(). So I wanted to know if this is an inbuilt R/Rstudio kind of setting